# Using Context free language to simulate regular expression in finite automata

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars, lower-bounds

Is there a minimum number of non terminal we need to use in order to simulate a finite automata with n states? When we try to convert a language accepted by NFA to context free language, do we need n number of non-terminal to store n states in the NFA?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51311/lower-bound-for-number-of-nonterminals-in-a-cfg). Do you guys have the same exercise sheet?

Answer (score 6):

No such non-trivial bound can be obtained. Consider the language $L_n = \{ 0^{kn} : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Any NFA for $L_n$ needs at least $n$ states, but it can be generated by a context-free grammar with only one non-terminal: $S\to 0^nS|\epsilon$.